# Show that the modulus function $f:R\to R$ given by

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Show that the modulus function $f:R\to R $ given by $f(x)=|x|$ is neither one one nor onto function when $|x|$ is $x$ if $x$ is positive or $0$ and $|x|$ is $-x$ if $x$ is negative.

My attempt :

$$f(x)=|x|\implies f(x)=x, f(x)=-x$$

Case $1$. Let $x_1\geq 0$ and $x_2\geq 0$.
$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$
$$x_1=x_2$$

Case$2$. Let $x_1\le 0$ and $x_2\le 0$
$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$
$$-x_1=-x_2$$
$$x_1=x_2$$

How do I show the function as neither one one nor onto?

Comment: You didn't consider when $x_1>0,x_2<0$

Comment: @KingW3,  what does that give?

Comment: It gives you $-x_1=x_2$ which is what you want.

Comment: @kingW3,  why should we consider that,too? Because the first two cases show the function is one one!

Comment: Because $x_1,x_2$ need not be of the same sign,so your first two cases are incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

It's not injective since $|-1| = |1|$. It's not surjective since for no $x$ is it the case that $|x| = -3$.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: What do you want to know? :P

Comment: how did you prove that the function is not injective and surjective?

Comment: Do you know what "injective" and "surjective" mean?

Comment: yeah. I know about them

Comment: Tell me their definitions.

Comment: A function is injective iff every image has maximum one pre-image

Comment: So is $|\cdot|$ injective, given that $|1| = |-1|$ has two preimages?

Comment: The function is surjective (onto) if every element of the codomain is mapped to by at least one element of the domain

Comment: So is $| \cdot |$ surjective, given that the element $-3$ of the codomain is not mapped to by any elements of the domain?

Comment: how did you get there? I am asking for some proper steps

Comment: Oh, do you mean "how did you come up with the examples of $1, -1, -3$"? Or do you mean "how do those examples prove the theorem"?

Comment: I mean both..!!!